# Stretching text navigational elements 100% across the screen with css

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm drawing a blank at how to make text dynamically grow and shrink to always fit a page perfectly so that various word groups always take up the full width of various screen sizes.

I'm on a phone browser right now, so excuse me if I don't post full html examples, but here is the gist of common scenarios that I'm trying to have a technique to resolve:

```
<div>
<div>
<a>nav element</a> <a>another</a><a>lots of text in this nav element</a>
</div>
<div>
 ... another set of links wwith different text here ... 
</div>
<div>
... and another ...
</div>

</div>
```

All told, the above layout would take up exactly three lines all the way across the screen on any screensize or window size.

A simpler example:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Wherein not only would the h1 have a width of 100% of the screen (easy) but the text content itself would grow in font-size to fit 100% of the screen.

Similar techniques that I am aware of:

Font-stretch // except it just squashes/stretches text without regard for the text containers

Font-size:5%; // except this deals with the vertical scale of each letter.

text-align:justify; // except it just adds space instead of scaling up the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a pure CSS way to accomplish this. I believe you have to use JS. There's several scripts and plugins out there for that. Here's one for jQuery:

http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can resort to js, I'm just amazed that anyone can build good looking navigation without being able to stretch the text in percentage-based ways.  Dunno how pros get anything looking right.  And I'm wondering if css3 has anything for this, because I haven't heard of anything.

Comment: Well, yeah, but not -first thing-.  They have to do something to their layout to make it work right first before they can rely on js user agents.

Comment: yes and no. JS is very much a valid tool and sometimes it's more pragmatic to use a little bit of JS than a lot of CSS. It all depends on the site, of course.

Answer (score 1):

[Media queries](http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/) is probably the closest thing that exists to what you are looking for. Another good term to search for is "Responsive Design", its been a fairly hot topic on most of the designer blogs I follow in the last few months.

Comment: that's not quite what is being asked. The question is how to have font-size dynamically scale so that the text filles the container.

Comment: Yup, and thats why I said its the closest thing that exists in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not with css.

Sorry.

You can probably program something with javascript.